# how to run a hive query on multiple dir's with multiple files

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, azure-hdinsight

I want to run a count hive query on multiple directories which have multiple files in them. Path to files looks like this

```
'2011/01/01/file20110101_01.csv
 2011/01/01/file20110101_02.csv
 2011/01/02/file20110201_01.csv
 2011/01/02/file20110201_02.csv'
```

and so on.

I created an external table with following partition

```
 'create external table table1(col1,col2...)
  partitioned by (year string,month string)
  STORED AS TEXTFILE'
```

and tried to add partition just till the month.

```
'ALTER TABLE partition_test_production1 ADD PARTITION(year='2011', month='01')
LOCATION 'blob path/2011/01/*/file201101*.csv';'
```

Tried this query

```
'select count(1) from table1 where year='2011' AND month='01';'
```

But the count is showing as zero. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to add all of the files individually, but you do have to add all of the bottom-level directories individually. When you add a directory, Hive reads all files in that directory, but not any files in sub-directories. For example:

```
create external table table1(col1,col2...)
partitioned by (year string, month string, day string)
STORED AS TEXTFILE

ALTER TABLE table1 ADD PARTITION(year='2011', month='01', day='01')
LOCATION 'hdfs:///path/2011/01/01/';

ALTER TABLE table1 ADD PARTITION(year='2011', month='01', day='02')
LOCATION 'hdfs:///path/2011/01/02/';

etc
```

Usually you would have a bash script or something do this. Loop over all the directories in hdfs and generate the hive statement to add that partition. I'm not a bash expert, but as an example:

```
hadoop fs -ls hdfs:///path/*/* | while read line; do
  year="$(echo "$line" | awk -F/ '{print $(NF-2)}')"
  month="$(echo "$line" | awk -F/ '{print $(NF-1)}')"
  day="$(echo "$line" | awk -F/ '{print $(NF)}')"
  hive -e "alter table table1 add partition(year='$year', month='$month', day='$day') location 'hdfs:///path/$year/$month/$day'"
done
```

There seems to be some old jira tickets about having table/partition locations be more flexible, but they're all unresolved.

Comment: yes i did create each partitions individually like the ones you mentioned. but i have sub directories(for days 01 to 30) under each month and i have multiple files under each day directory. Is there a way to include all these day directories using a single query.

Comment: No, there is not. I should clarify- you have to add all of the bottom-level directories individually, so in your case, down to the "day". Notice that in my example, I added a day partition column and am adding deeper directories.

Comment: i am sorry, i should have mentioned before. i am trying to do it in microsoft azure hdinsight, not in HDFS. i cannot run a shell script here.

Comment: I have no experience with microsoft's stack, but surely you can run some sort of script, even if it's not shell? You just have to be able to programmatically loop over directories and do some basic text manipulation to transform them into "add partition" statements.

Comment: Hi Joe, Can you please have a look at this question.                      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766449/creating-hive-partitions-for-multiple-months-using-one-script

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to create partitions manually. If you have created an external table and data resides in this directories, you can run the **msck repair table table_name** and it will automatically load all the partitions.