# Creating hive partitions for multiple months using one script

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, azure-hdinsight

I have data for 4 years. Like

```
'2011
 2012
 2013
 2014'
```

I have to run queries based on one month's data. So i am creating partitions as below.

```
'ALTER TABLE table1_2010Jan ADD PARTITION(year='2010', month='01', day='01')
 LOCATION 'path';
 ALTER TABLE table1_2010Jan ADD PARTITION(year='2010', month='01', day='02')
 LOCATION 'path';
 ALTER TABLE table1_2010Jan ADD PARTITION(year='2010', month='01', day='03')
 LOCATION 'path';'
```

I am creating individual partitions like above for every day of every month.

I want to know if we can write a script(any language) an run it one time to create these partitions for the all the days of a month for every year? Or is there a way to do this in hive itself.

Any suggestions please..

Comment: why do you need to create partitions? If its for inserting data you can always insert using dynamic partitions and they will be created for you.

Have a look here : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/DynamicPartitions

Comment: I have data already available on blob. I first created a external table. Now i am trying to create partitions for each day and point the partition to the location of data

Answer (score 1):

For external table , hive can not do it. You can create shell/perl script to to do the same (using loop).

For hive managed table, you can do it easily using MSCK REPAIR command.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions%28MSCKREPAIRTABLE%29

Only thing you have to ensure that the data is loaded is correct partition.

Comment: MSCK REPAIR works on external tables too. It takes longer, scans the whole table and creates all available partitions. Often, the intent is to create partitions only for a subset of the dates\partitions